# Jquery form fields validation pop up missing icon on Iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, validation

This is a jquery form input validation pop up validation on Android, working as expected and with icon:

[image]

This is a jquery form input validation pop update validation on Iphone. Icon missing.

[image]

is it correct to think this is jquery library specific problem for iPhone, that should be expected to be fixed in next jquery update for iPhone right?

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a jQueryUI issue, not a jQuery one. Also, given that jQueryUI is no longer actively updated (it's last update was September 2016) I wouldn't hold out on this ever being fixed. I'd suggest finding a better library, for example, Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixing this by my own makes sense?
It will implies touching the core of jQueryUI right?

Comment: You could do it that way, but that's not what I'm suggesting. I am advising that you remove jQueryUI as it's outdated and no longer maintained and use something else.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery, and jQuery Validate does not render as tooltips.  You're showing us screenshots of the default HTML5 validation that is built into each browser, which is why it looks different on each browser.  There seems to be no programming question here, but if you're using jQuery Validate, it's definitely not being triggered; and editing jQuery UI would have no effect on this.  Your jQuery validation is not doing anything, and it's falling back onto HTML5.